# How Do I Autofill a Column Where the Data is Being Pulled from Another Sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, vba

Generally this would be a simple task, however, I am working between two sheets. The first sheet is my Summary sheet, the sheet I am using to summarize my data that I will later use to build some charts.

[image: Summery Sheet]

The other sheet I am working in is "Kickstarterscrape_06-02-201", this sheet contains all of my organized data.

[image: Data Sheet:Kickstarter Scrape]

My goal is to pull the data from my data sheet: Kickstarter scrape, for number of projects by location and summarize it on the summary page under the country table. I have already done this with a few locations. For example, I have been pulling the values as such: =COUNTIF('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!X:X,"Afghanistan"). However, I have 144 locations. Is there a way to summarize this data without having to copy, paste, and edit the function =COUNTIF('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!X:X," ") every single time? Thanks!

Comment: `=COUNTIF('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!X:X,B24)` Then drag down the country list.

Comment: Just create a PivotTable.  Put 'location' in your row labels quadrant and put 'location' again in your values quadrant.  This will count each location.  PivotTables are awesome and provide the easiest way to summarize data.  Any questions, just ask :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks, it worked! Do you want to answer the question directly as well? I want to make sure you get credit. I can't mark the question as answered through the comment section.

Comment: @CRUTER, thanks for the assistance. I am currently learning PivotTables, so I will also play with this method.

Comment: @JakeGirouard you can always up-vote our comments :)

Comment: @CRUTER I don't have that capability yet. I think I have to earn another badge or two. Once I am able to, I will make sure to up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just placing this answer here so the question is mark answered for future visitors.

`=COUNTIF('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!X:X,B24)`

Then drag down the country list